# Real Time clock module error-DS3231

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, hardware, rtc, ds3231-alarms

This is not a code error I have been using DS3231 RTC module with battery. When I bought this module It worked perfectly now when I get it to use, The time is running perfectly. when I set the current time of my location, it has been running along with that time but the problem is when I unplug the power of my Arduino Nano and again when I give the power I can see the time is running from its start, I could not see any current time value my location but I have attached CR2032 battery along with DS3231 module? what is the problem with this? I changed another battery too but It shows same problem my DS32321 haven't kept the time when I unplug and re-plug the power

This is the code I'm using for set the time

```
#include <DS3231.h>

// Init the DS3231 using the hardware interface
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);

void setup()
{
  // Setup Serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Uncomment the next line if you are using an Arduino Leonardo
  //while (!Serial) {}
  
  // Initialize the rtc object
  rtc.begin();
  
  // The following lines can be uncommented to set the date and time
  rtc.setDOW(WEDNESDAY);     // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
  rtc.setTime(12, 0, 0);     // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
  rtc.setDate(1, 1, 2014);   // Set the date to January 1st, 2014
}

void loop()
{
  // Send Day-of-Week
  Serial.print(rtc.getDOWStr());
  Serial.print(" ");
  
  // Send date
  Serial.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  Serial.print(" -- ");

  // Send time
  Serial.println(rtc.getTimeStr());
  
  // Wait one second before repeating :)
  delay (1000);
}
```

This is the code I'm using to make Interrupt

```
 #include <DS3231.h>

int Relay = 4;

DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
Time t;

const int OnHour = 21;
const int OnMin = 46;
const int OffHour = 21;
const int OffMin = 48;

const int On2Hour = 14;
const int On2Min = 54;
const int Off2Hour = 21;
const int Off2Min = 48;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Time:  ");
  Serial.print(rtc.getTimeStr());
  Serial.print('\n');

  Serial.println("Date: ");
  Serial.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  Serial.print('\n');

  t = rtc.getTime();
  Serial.print(t.hour);
  Serial.print(" hour(s), ");
  Serial.print(t.min);
  Serial.print(" minute(s)");
  Serial.println(" ");
  delay (1000);
  //can be set lcd display alspo
  if(t.hour == OnHour && t.min == OnMin){
    digitalWrite(Relay,HIGH);
    Serial.println("LIGHT ON");
    }
    
    else if(t.hour == OffHour && t.min == OffMin){
      digitalWrite(Relay,LOW);
      Serial.println("LIGHT OFF");
    }
  if(t.hour == On2Hour && t.min == On2Min){
    digitalWrite(Relay,HIGH);
    Serial.println("LIGHT ON");
    }
    
    else if(t.hour == Off2Hour && t.min == Off2Min){
      digitalWrite(Relay,LOW);
      Serial.println("LIGHT OFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code and which library are you using

Comment: I'm using Ds3231 library

Comment: yeah now I have uploaded the code

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a code please try it may be it can help you

```
    #include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(57600);

#ifndef ESP8266
  while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
#endif

  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    Serial.flush();
    abort();
  }

  if (rtc.lostPower()) {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, let's set the time!");
    // When time needs to be set on a new device, or after a power loss, the
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
    // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
     rtc.adjust(DateTime(2020, 10, 19, 10, 13, 0));
  }

  // When time needs to be re-set on a previously configured device, the
  // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
  // rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
  // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
  // rtc.adjust(DateTime(2014, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0));
}

void loop () {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();

    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(" (");
    Serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
    Serial.print(") ");
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.print(" since midnight 1/1/1970 = ");
    Serial.print(now.unixtime());
    Serial.print("s = ");
    Serial.print(now.unixtime() / 86400L);
    Serial.println("d");

    // calculate a date which is 7 days and 30 seconds into the future
    DateTime future (now + TimeSpan(7,12,30,6));

    Serial.print(" now + 7d + 30s: ");
    Serial.print(future.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(future.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(future.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(future.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(future.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(future.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(rtc.getTemperature());
    Serial.println(" C");

    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
}
```

Upload the above code and then upload the same code just comment the following part

```
if (rtc.lostPower()) {
        Serial.println("RTC lost power, let's set the time!");
        // When time needs to be set on a new device, or after a power loss, the
        // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
        rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
        // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
        // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
         rtc.adjust(DateTime(2020, 10, 19, 10, 13, 0));
      }
```

This will work and even if you plug and unplug it from power the RTC time will not reset

Comment: is it ok with Arduino

Comment: No,  it's not working, It shows the same problem that I have been facing. I mean my RTC module ds3231 does not keep time when it loses it power. but  I have attached timekeeping battery along with that

Comment: The same above code was working for me have you checked the voltage of the battery and also have you uncommented the part of the code and uploaded it again?

Comment: yeah , your  code is working fine , I changed the new battery too, but the problems is when it loses it power it starts from 2000/0/1 and the time is starting with 00.00.01

Comment: Okay 2000/0/1 is the starting time of ds3231, have you checked the voltage using multimeter check the polarity of the battery also before inserting it in the module and can you please share the picture of your module and also how have you inserted the battery

Comment: yeah I have to check the voltage using multimeter but the battery is new one and I have attached the battery in a proper way. I could not send the image through this platform because it is a large file

Comment: If you send your email I cand send it through that

Comment: Attach it in your above post everyone can answer then even if I am unable to answer it

Comment: yeah I tried that but it contains a large file size

Comment: Upload it over [here](https://gofile.io/uploadFiles)

Comment: Use any software to reduce the size (resolution / bit depth / compression).

Comment: ok here is my ds3231 image https://gofile.io/d/9IkuBr

Comment: Now I checked my rtc module it shows 3.3v across the ds3231 module but it doesn't keep the time

Comment: I don't have access to my hardware right now will get back once I have access to my hardware, have you commented the part of the code which I have mentioned in the above code and tried again just want to know all the possibilities

Comment: 2020/10/19 (Monday) 10:14:5
 since midnight 1/1/1970 = 1603102445s = 18554d
 now + 7d + 30s: 2020/10/26 22:44:11
Temperature: 33.75 C

This was the output when I upload your code as per your instruction

Comment: ⸮⸮:b⸮⸮⸮\{⸮8k⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮2000/1/1 (Saturday) 0:0:5
 since midnight 1/1/1970 = 946684805s = 10957d
 now + 7d + 30s: 2000/1/8 12:30:11
Temperature: 33.75 C

this is the output message when I unplug and re-plug the power of my Arduino

Comment: Posting a schematic not a frizzy picture, as how you have it wired showing all connections could eliminate a lot of the problems. Perfect software with the wrong hardware configuration will not work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a SWAG as I do not know what module you are having problems. Remove the battery, power it up and measure the voltage at the battery terminals. If you have about 3.2V the module is designed to charge the battery (thought you might like to know). Power down the module insert the battery, do not power it up, and measure the battery voltage at the chip. Be sure to also check the ground side. I believe you will find the same thing I did, the solder connection to the battery holder was open, just added some solder and that solved it. I also found the SCL line was  broken on the board so if I connected the other side it would not work. I added a jumper to fix it. I purchased several from azon but only the first one was bad.